How to ensure a specific GPU is used in Windows 10?
Let me preface this by stating that I am a Linux man, so I'm not so used to dealing with Windows. Bear with me here.

I have a custom-built PC which I got on eBay and which has been working quite well for me since I got it. However, over the past few days, I've been noticing that Windows doesn't seem to be making use of the GPU. Whenever I try to run any program heavier than a web browser, I get an almost instant crash — and not a system freeze, either. The entire display blacks out, and I'm left with a "No Signal" message on the monitor.
After some research, I used Task Manager's Performance tab to monitor the performance while I loaded up a game (The Finals, specifically). Up to the moment that the game crashed (which was just after starting a match), the GPU load was at 0%. My system has integrated graphics, but Task Manager confirmed that these weren't being used either. I've been able to replicate this error several times on two separate games (the only ones I have installed).
What can I do to get this working?
P.S.: I suspect that this problem arose because I've had to re-seat the GPU several times recently. It's a clunky workaround I've found for some other occasional, minor display issues that I've had with my dual-boot Windows/Linux systems. Just thought I'd mention it in case it might be useful to know.
Also, here are my system specs as generated by the NVIDIA app:
NVIDIA app version: 11.0.1.163
Operating system: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.19045
DirectX runtime version: DirectX 12
Driver: Game Ready Driver - 566.14 - Tue Nov 12, 2024
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
RAM: 16.0 GB
Storage (4): SSD - 1.8 TB,SSD - 953.9 GB,+2 more

Graphics card
GPU processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
Direct3D feature level: 12_1
CUDA cores: 1408
Graphics clock: 1815 MHz
Resizable bar: No
Memory data rate: 14.00 Gbps
Memory interface: 192-bit
Memory bandwidth: 336.048 GB/s
Total available graphics memory: 14281 MB
Dedicated video memory: 6144 MB GDDR6
System video memory: 0 MB
Shared system memory: 8137 MB
Video BIOS version: 90.16.48.00.2e
IRQ: Not used
Bus: PCI Express x16 Gen3
Device ID: 10DE 21C4 C75A1462
Part number: G161 0026

Display (1): 2429W
Resolution: 1080p, 1920 x 1080 (native)
Refresh rate: 60 Hz
Desktop color depth: Highest (32-bit)
HDCP: Supported


Installing the Nvidia driver and not installing the iGPU should mean only the Nvidia device is used. Evidence suggests that’s exactly the case

This might sound silly but just double checking, you've plugged the monitor into a port on the GPU and not the motherboard right?

@MC10 Yes, directly into the GPU
